# Why do we need to move "if" statement?

Tags: python

I don't understand why moving:

```
if cipher_direction == "decode":
      shift_amount *= -1
```

under `end_text` works, but it doesn't work in the position shown below?

[image: screenshot]

The full code:

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

#TODO-1: Combine the encrypt() and decrypt() functions into a single function
# called caesar().

def caesar(start_text, shift_amount, cipher_direction):
  end_text = ""
  if cipher_direction == "decode":
      shift_amount *= -1
  for letter in start_text:
    position = alphabet.index(letter)
    new_position = position + shift_amount
    end_text += alphabet[new_position]
  print(f"Here's the {direction}d result: {end_text}")


#TODO-2: Call the caesar() function, passing over the 'text', 'shift' and
# 'direction' values.
caesar(start_text=text, shift_amount=shift, cipher_direction=direction)
```

Comment: Because, if at the beginning, `shift_amount` is subjected to change its sign at most once (if `if` succeeds). When it is inside, it is subjected to change sign the number of times that *for* loop goes on (again, if `cipher_direction == "decode"`).

Comment: If it was in the middle, it would continually alternate back and forth. A Caesar cipher is monodirectional, so reversing it many times is silly. Decoding, it just reverse the encoding process, hence the reverse direction.

Comment: Aside from your question, I suggest you learn about the modulo `%` operator, rather than having a duplicated list of letters.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable assignment (*=) is constantly overwritten in a loop.
To use it in a loop, it needs to be assigned once.

For example:

```
def caesar(start_text, shift_amount, cipher_direction):
  end_text = ""
  #if cipher_direction == "decode":
  #  shift_amount *= -1
  for letter in start_text:
    if cipher_direction == "decode" and shift_amount > 0:
      shift_amount *= -1
    position = alphabet.index(letter)
    new_position = position + shift_amount
    end_text += alphabet[new_position]
    print(f"Here's the {direction}d result: {end_text}")
```

> NOTE : The program throws an error in the words with spaces.